# Manually add Template 10 to an existing UWP project?

Tags: template10

I have a UWP app that I created using one of the Azure templates, can I add Template 10 to it manually? If so what are the steps? Is it as easy as adding the references and coping over the chucks of code from an existing project?

It might be easier going the opposite route and moving the pertinent code over from the Azure app to a Template 10 app.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually easier than I expected, although wiki post on the GitHub repository would be helpful. These are the steps that I took.

1. Created a blank Template 10 app for reference.
2. Added the Template 10 NuGet package to the project.
3. Copy and pasted all of the relevant code over from the reference project to my existing project.
4. Built and cleaned the solution, refreshed the project, and then it would run.